# Gradle / Java Access Denied by wsimport task

Tags: java, windows, gradle, java-8, wsimport

I can't find solution for this problem: my gradle build has some problem with access to some files during build. How can I fix this or check why there is access denied, there is only little information for it.

System is Windows 7, Gradle 2.14.1, JDK 1.8.0-181.

Here is part of log from GIT Bash output:

```
Importing wsdl: C:\dev\wsdl\someWsdl.wsdl
[wsimport] [ERROR] C:\dev\src\main\java\com\project\SomeClass.java (Access is denied)
```

I have tried:

- running console as "Run as administrator"
- running from CMD and Git Bash and Power Shell
- changing Security access rights (and owner) for project folder and JDK folder

Comment: Maybe you should try disable your antivirus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling antivirus protection of McAfee has fixed my issues.